# Creating DateTime object in Visual C++

Tags: datetime, visual-c++

I am familiar with creating DateTime object based on current system time

```
DateTime dtObject = DateTime::Now;
```

My question is: if I have integer variables iHour, iMinute and iSecond, how do I "put them back" into a DateTime object?

I hope I made myself clear. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of

```
DateTime today = DateTime::Today;
DateTime todayWithTime(today.Year, today.Month, today.Day,
                       hour, minute, second);
```

Another approach:

```
DateTime todayWithTime = DateTime::Today + TimeSpan(hour, minute, second);
```

Comment: I don't want to have date in my DateTime object, just the time. And as far as I know, creating it like `DateTime justTime (h,m,s) ` will accept h,m and s as year, month and day.

Comment: Well, it's called `DateTime` for a reason. If you want just time without date, you are looking for `TimeSpan`.

Comment: I don't know why I thought TimeSpan was used for calculating difference between two DateTime objects. Thank you so much, kind sir!

Comment: It's used for that, too.